# How to test error handling functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I m trying to write unit test cases to handle error codes that are defined below. not sure how to achieve it.

```
module.exports = {
    Error: Err,
    BadRequest: function () {
        return new Err(400, 'Bad Request');
    },
    NotAcceptable: function () {
        return new Err(406, 'Not Acceptable');
    },
    NotAuthorized: function () {
        return new Err(401, 'Not Authorized');
    }
};

function Err(code, message) {
    assert(code, 'code');

    Error.call(this);
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'code', {
        enumerable: true,
        value: code
    });

    this.reason = message;
}
```

Comment: Look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error, you can throw error and try-catch some block of code.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a better base error layer by extending the `Error` class which already provide most of the functions you would need (capturing the stack trace automatically):

```
class Err extends Error {
    constructor(code, message) {
        super(message);
        this.code = code;
        this.reason = message;
    }
}
```

You can then performa your assertion using the `throw` expectation:

```
const errorFn = () => { throw new Err(401, 'Unauthorized') };

expect(errorFn).to.throw(Err).to.haveOwnProperty('code', 401).to.haveOwnProperty('reason', 'Unauthorized');
```

*You should obviously update your sub-error accordingly to extend your generic error.*

Comment: thanks @tmarwen , this helps, although my test case is failing - > ReferenceError: Err is not defined, where do i define Err ?